# C++| Declare class outside function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino

When I try to declare **log_.h** which I included in rckt_test.ino(equal to .cpp) The compiler gives me that exception: `rckt_test.ino: 9:6: error: 'log_ log' redeclared as different kind of symbol
   log_ log`. But I ve never been declaring this class anywhere else before. Is it even possible to declare the **log_** class outside a function?

**rckt_test.ino(.cpp)**:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "log_.h"

// Settings 
bool log_file = true; // Depends on availabilty of SD Cart reader

// Defining log class
log_ log;

void setup() {

   Serial.begin(9600);

   log.log_init(log_file);

   log.log_text("Rocket startup");

}

void loop() {
}
```

**log_.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>


class log_ {
    private:
        void print_text(String text);
        void save_to_log_file(String text);
        static bool log_in_file;
    public:
        void log_init(bool file_loggging);
        void log_text(String text);
};
```

Error:

```
Compiling debug version of 'rckt_test' for 'Arduino Nano w/ ATmega328P'

rckt_test.ino: 9:6: error: 'log_ log' redeclared as different kind of symbol
log_ log

arduino.h:26: In file included from
rckt_test.ino: from
math.h:305: note  previous declaration double log(double)
extern double log(double __x) __ATTR_CONST__

rckt_test.ino: In function void setup()

rckt_test.ino: 15:5: error: request for member 'log_init' in 'log', which is 
of non-class type 'double(double)
log.log_init(log_file)

rckt_test.ino: 17:5: error: request for member 'log_text' in 'log', which is 
of non-class type 'double(double)
log.log_text("Rocket startup")

log_.cpp: 29:42: error: no 'void log_::log_in_file_setter(bool)' member 
function declared in class 'log_
void log_*: log_in_file_setter(bool setter) {

log_.cpp: 33:31: error: no 'bool log_::log_in_file_getter()' member function 
declared in class 'log_
bool log_*: log_in_file_getter() {
Error compiling project sources
Debug build failed for project 'rckt_test'
```

Comment: From your error message it looks like there is a function named `log` somewhere in `Arduino.h`. Try renaming `log` to something else, or put it in a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows the other declaration of `log` came from `math.h`, which is function declaration for mathematical logarithm. Rename the variable from `log` to something else or wrap it in a different `namespace`.

Comment: Or consider `<cmath>`, which may define just `std::log` and not put it in the global namespace. Unfortunately this is not always a working solution as some vendors insist on polluting the global namespace.